# How to install yum in Red Hat 3.4.6-3

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

I want to use the `yum` command in Red Hat 3.4.6-3. How can I install it?

Answer (score 7):

- Download the yum version of your choice: wget http://linux.duke.edu/projects/yum/download/2.0/yum-2.0.7.tar.gz
- Untar the package: tar xvzf yum-2.0.7.tar.gz
- change directory into the newly expanded folder: cd yum-2.0.7
- run the configuration file: ./configure
- make configuration: make
- make installation: make install

Comment: I am getting this error Gathering header information file(s) from server(s) Server: Red Hat Linux 4ES - i386 - Base retrygrab() failed for: mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/4ES/i386/… Executing failover method failover: out of servers to try Error getting file mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/4ES/i386/… [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error > –

Comment: Move your existing /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file and replace those Fedora repositories with the actual CentOS-Base.repo ones:
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.bak
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/easyapache-hangs-during-build-171006.html Please take a look!

Answer (score 1):

download  `yum-2.4.2-0.4.el4.rf.noarch.rpm`  and install using `rpm -ivh yum-2.4.2-0.4.el4.rf.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I am getting this error Gathering header information file(s) from server(s)
Server: Red Hat Linux 4ES - i386 - Base
retrygrab() failed for:
  http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/4ES/i386/headers/header.info
  Executing failover method
failover: out of servers to try
Error getting file http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/4ES/i386/headers/header.info
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error >